# Adding function-call listening to Javascript for debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, reflection

So I've had an idea, but need some help to get it to actually work.
Or maybe it's impossible and stupid, in which case let me know why.

The idea is to allow the programmer to be able to this:

```
lookfor('alert');
```

After this line of code is run, whenever the alert function is called the console logs a backtrace. This is so in big (group) projects it's easier to find where javascript code is being triggered.

So I guess the question is about modifying functions without knowing their content, rather than overriding them completely. I have a feeling this is going to be possible for user defined functions and not built in functions like alert(). My first thought for user defined functions was something like this:

```
function lookfor(func_name)
{
    var override = window[func_name].toString();

    override = override.replace(/(.*?){(.*?)}/, 'printBacktrace(); $2');

    window[func_name] = new Function(override);
}
```

Although it presumably only works for global functions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint in the function in question?

Comment: The function is for convenience more than anything. Sometimes the functions are nested deep in minified code. Also doesn't resolve the issue of built in functions.